# vscode on WSL issue: editing cursor goes backward when opening bracket or braces

Tags: linux, windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running vscode into a Debian WSL subsystem on top of my Windows 10 workstation, thanks to Xfce4 window-session and vcXsrv X server.

I'm working on a Python 3 project and I have a strange behavior with my vscode editor running on WSL that I can't reproduce with either the native Windows or Linux build : Let's say in want to access a dict key, I'd type the following code:

```
my_dict[
```

here I'm expecting IntelliSense auto-close the bracket and keep the cursor *between* the brackets. This what usually happens (at least with my native vscode on Windows and on my vscode on my /real/ Linux box). But this is not what happens on my WSL !

Seems the cursors goes backward **before** actually typing the open bracket so the bracket is typed one char earlier, and finally don't close the bracket, To be clearI get the following typed in the editor:

```
my_dic[t
```

If I workaround by typing a space **before** typing the opening bracket, I get the same behavior but this time as the earlier char is a space IntelliSense is functionning /almost/ as expected, forwarding the typed space at the end of line (bellow the '$' represents EOL) :

```
my_dict[] $
```

I experienced this with brackets ([]) and also braces ({}), with python code and also JSON files, so I don't wonder this is related to language extension.

Last but not least, the only installed extension, is "Python 2019.1.0" by Microsoft and the setup is full stock with no customization at all...

I spent hours reading vscode documentation and browsing for similar issue, with no luck (maybe wrong keywords ?), so any hint will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Sorry for my late reply,

Actually I'm using a french keyboard so '[' or '{' characters are obtained using 'alt gr' key in combinaison with other keys, so I discovered that the 'alt gr' key press provoke the issue I described earlier...

Then I made a new search and I found this issue that describes perfectly (and better than I did) my problem : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24783

So the solution consists of modifying vscode setting "keyboard.dispatch" with "keyCode" value !

Sorry for the noise

Answer (score 0):

In the backend, you're still utilizing conhost from the Windows Console to run all your terminal commands. Some cursor behaviors don't work properly in earlier builds of Windows on WSL (but do work fine on Windows). Try to update to the latest and see if you still encounter the issue. If you do then, check for an issue in https://github.com/Microsoft/console and create one if not there.